# How to measure disk's "average response time" as in Windows 8.1 Task manager

Tags: c#, .net, windows, performancecounter

If you open Windows 8.1 Task Manager, choose "More details", "Performance" tab, and "Disk 0" item, you'll see "Average response time" value expressed in milliseconds.

How to get this value using `PerformanceCounter` class?

Here are counters I use:

```
    static PerformanceCounterCategory PhysicalDiskCategory = new PerformanceCounterCategory("PhysicalDisk");
    static List<string> PhysicalDisks = new List<string>(PhysicalDiskCategory.GetInstanceNames());
    static string Disk0Instance = PhysicalDisks.FirstOrDefault(i => i.StartsWith("0"));
    static PerformanceCounter DiskTimeCounter = new PerformanceCounter("PhysicalDisk", "% Disk Time", Disk0Instance);
    static PerformanceCounter DiskTransferCounter = new PerformanceCounter("PhysicalDisk", "Disk Bytes/sec", Disk0Instance);
    static PerformanceCounter DiskAvgSecTransferCounter = new PerformanceCounter("PhysicalDisk", "Avg. Disk sec/Transfer", Disk0Instance);
    static PerformanceCounter DiskAvgQueueLengthCounter = new PerformanceCounter("PhysicalDisk", "Avg. Disk Queue Length", Disk0Instance);
```

None of them gives me the value, however "Avg. Disk Queue Length" seems to be closely related to "Average response time". It seems reasonable - the more disk latency - the longer disk queue gets. But how does Task Manager get it? Is it calculated from more than one counter?

BTW, How to tell the difference between low impact background disk operations (run Windows Defender full scan to observe this) from high impact ones (during Windows startup)?

Shortly after you get to the Windows desktop the computer is very unresponsive, next to useless, for a couple of minutes (or seconds if you have fast SSD). This is related to disk time. When you wait until disk time drops below 50% - system is perfectly responsive.

However it's not the case when disk time over 90% is caused by Windows Defender or other background tasks. It doesn't affect system responsiveness. Hibernate and restore system. You'll notice disk time over 90% for at least a minute (up to 5 minutes on mine). But there is no problem with system responsiveness. Visual Studio starts almost immediately. There are no lags on opening big projects.

I figured out that shortly after reboot "Average response time" is huge compared to values measured while AV scan. This could be exactly it - a way to measure REAL system responsiveness. But how do they get it? How to get it in .NET app?

Comment: This is [I/O Prioritization](http://download.microsoft.com/download/a/f/7/af7777e5-7dcd-4800-8a0a-b18336565f5b/Priorityio.doc) at work, first added to Vista.  The odds that you can get enough insight in what I/O requests are out-standing and what priority they have ought to be exceedingly low.

Comment: Thanks. The document you've linked to shows a hint how to check process IO priority, this could be used to calculate total IO load by priority level. But from there it would be ridiculously hard to get to total system responsiveness and latencies. It depends on too many factors. So far I used "% Disk Time" and "Avg. Disk Queue Length" counters with promising results. Most of the time I detect real responsiveness lags and succeed to ignore non-blocking disk IO. Of course there's a smart algorithm using tresholds and hysteresis to detect the lags.

Comment: I've not found any meaning in "Average response time" - infact I've run sqlio disk bench marks on an SSD that see this figure blow out to 32 seconds - all the while, the benchmark is pulling 500MB and 50k iops.

Comment: ..Just got 128,000 ms average repsonse time. System is not unresponsive what so ever.

Comment: Did you ever discover how to get that Average Response Time?

Comment: Nope. I don't know how Microsoft gets it. But "Avg. Disk Queue Length" seems to be good for determining system responsiveness related to disk I/O. Since I bought SSD, disk queue hardly ever exceeds 1. Seems to be retro/vintage PC thing now. Of course I use mechanical disks for data storage, but they don't impact SYSTEM responsiveness. System just SHOULD be on SSD, period. BTW, although I strain my SSD with extreme amount of writes (app tests with ca 2GB of writes per test) - no single I/O error so far.